# how to set the shmmax parameter on mac os x

Tags: mac, shmmax

how should I set the shm* values in Mac Os X 10.5.6 Leopard in a persistent manner?

Comment: sorry, actually this works. I just had a typo and edited the wrong file syslog.conf...

Comment: I changed the original wording, and put the solution as answer (only to help somebody else)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

put this

```
kern.sysv.shmmax=524288000
kern.sysv.shmmin=1
kern.sysv.shmmni=64
kern.sysv.shmseg=16
kern.sysv.semmns=130
kern.sysv.shmall=131072000
kern.sysv.maxproc=2048
kern.maxprocperuid=512
```

on this file /etc/sysctl.conf

and then reboot.

to verify run this command

```
 sysctl kern.sysv.shmmax
```

and it should give 524288000

Comment: If you don't want to reboot you can do it this way and it will be updated until your next reboot: `sudo sysctl -w kern.sysv.shmmax=xxxxx`

Answer (score 4):

(from: http://willbryant.net/software/mac_os_x/postgres_initdb_fatal_shared_memory_error_on_leopard)

One wat to fix it is to run:

```
sudo sysctl -w kern.sysv.shmall=65536
sudo sysctl -w kern.sysv.shmmax=16777216
```

and then run the initdb command. To persist the changes you need to edit/create the file `/etc/sysctl.conf`
with this:

```
kern.sysv.shmall=65536
kern.sysv.shmmax=16777216
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you get when you run 'sysctl -p' ? does it load your settings from /etc/sysctl.conf?  What file is listed as default when you do 'sysctl --help' ?

Comment: thanks for your response, I just wrote the wrong command to edit the wrong file. /etc/sysctl.conf works as expected.